# Invalid start tag

Tags: java, android, xml

For one of my XML files in my Java project I get a "Invalid Start Tag LinearLayout"
I cannot figure out how to statisfy Eclipse by fixing this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/chooseSuitLayout"
android:layout_width="275dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="top" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/chooseSuitText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Choose a suit."
android:textSize="16sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/suitSpinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawSeelectionOnTop="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/okButton"
android:layout_width="125dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me, at first glance. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: Where are you actually getting this error? Is it in the eclipse "Problems" window, or does it happen at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml seem right to me.

try to check if the xml is in the right directory if not:

Put your xml to the right directory

```
res/layout
```

after that clean and build your project

Answer (score 0):

The error occur when the firts tag, in this case 'LinearLayout', is in a wrong place. To resolve it move the .xml file to res/layout. If there is no such directory, make it in res/ and move .xml file. Then it will be build